# execute command after switch to different user with sudo

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to execute this command:

```
echo hello | sudo su - dp-postgres
```

But I get this:

```
-bash: line 1: hello: command not found
```

I also tried this:

```
sudo su - dp-postgres -c 'echo hello'
```

But that is asking me for the current user's password.

I need to switch to `dp-postgres` and then after execute any command as `dp-postgres` user.

Comment: (1) "that is asking me for the current user's password" – Do you want to be asked `dp-postgres`'s password? or to be allowed without any password? (2) "and then after execute any command" – Do you mean "any command not known in advance"? i.e. do you want an interactive shell? Or do you mean any command known in advance, like `echo hello` in your example? Please [edit] and clarify. (3) `echo 'echo hello' | sudo su - dp-postgres` may or may not work. Try and report back ([edit]) (4) Properly configured and used `sudo` without `su` may suffice. Or `su` without `sudo`, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` command permits to execute a command as another user. By default, it will ask for the current user password, it's the normal behavior (obviously, the user must also have the `sudo` usage permission). If you want to prevent the password asking behavior, you need to change your `/etc/sudoers` file and use `NOPASSWD` option which will allow you to run sudo without being asked for a password.

For your command, you can do something like :

```
sudo su - dp-postgres <<-EOF
  echo hello
EOF
```

Your second command should work as well :

```
sudo su - dp-postgres -c 'echo hello'
```

Here is an example :

```
$ sudo su - -c 'echo hello; id'
hello
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Password is not require on my side because initial user is in the `sudo` group and has something like that :

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

In the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: What's with this `sudo su` ? You really don't need both; what you're writing is equivalent to "_`sudo`: please make me root ... ok ... and now run `su`. Hello `su`, despite me now already being root, please make me root ... ok_"

Answer (score 0):

As has been written elsewhere, the `sudo` command allows a suitably authorised user to execute a command as someone else. By default, this *someone else* is root but (subject to authorisation) it can be any user. Also, by default `sudo` will ask for the current user's password.

If you want to run the `echo hello` command as the `dp-postgres` user, you can do this:

```
sudo -u dp-postgres echo hello
```

If you need the login environment set up, include `-i`:

```
sudo -iu dp-postgres echo hello
```

Note that these two examples do not change first to the `root` user and then to the `dp-postgres` user, so you can choose to set up a custom `sudoers` entry to allow access to this `dp-postgres` user but not to `root`. This is a good solution for a multiuser environment where access to `root` should be restricted and/or managed. (However, I note that you already have access to `root`, so you won't gain anything by a second, more restrictive, entry.)